# Automatically download and run standalone Java app from Maven

Tags: java, maven, deployment, aether

I would like to have an application/script that I could use to execute a stand alone Java application (i.e. a basic class with a main method) from a given Maven artifact.  Based on my research nothing like this currently exists, but I thought I'd ask the question to the community and see if anyone knows of a project that could support my needs.

The idea would be that I would pass in, either via a config file or the command line, a Maven artifact spec (group ID, artifact ID, and version) along with a fully qualified class name and a list of arguments.  The given artifact and all of its dependencies would then be downloaded (or not if they're already in the local repo) and the application would be launched with the appropriate classpath.

At this point I don't think it will be too difficult to implement a system that does this using the [Aether library](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) and Java's ProcessBuilder, but I was wondering if anyone else knew of an existing project that already handles this before I start reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I've accomplished something very close by having a pom file that specifies the project that has the class you want to run as a depedency. Then I run "mvn package" followed by "mvn exec:java" to run the class.

To do this for an arbitrary class would require dynamic modification of that pom file.

Comment: @Chris that's a good idea as several others have pointed out.  I just threw together a quick pom as a proof of concept and you don't even need to run "mvn package".  I set the packaging of the dummy project to "pom" and just ran "mvn exec:java" directly.

Comment: that's where stack overflow really starts to work: thanks for helping me!

Comment: [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/) should be able to help to download artifacts using their Maven coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is obvious, but why wont the exec plugin work? http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.project.App
```

If com.project.App were part of another jar, you would include it as a dependency like you normally would.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that.  I've used the exec plugin to run classes from the current project, but didn't even think of just adding my target artifact as a single dependency.  I'm glad I asked the question before writing my own implementation.  Thanks!

Comment: I just realized one of the down sides to this solution is that STDOUT gets muddied up with all the Maven output.  Not a huge issue, but it does make it a little less desirable for my specific application.

Comment: Yes ... but this whole approach (using Maven as an installer-cum-executor for a one-off command execution) is clunky and inefficient: all that downloading of plugins and dependencies.  There are much better ways; e.g. JNLP or downloading an executable uber-JAR file.

Comment: One man's inefficient downloads is another man's efficient development effort. For us, a research lab, we don't expect many users and have limited resources. Making maven do double duty keeps things simple.

Answer (score 2):

Running an application using Maven is pretty simple. I wonder if this something that you are looking at or did I get the question wrong?

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.test.foo.Main" -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just pushed to Maven Central the [Installation plugin](https://github.com/chaschev/maven-installation-plugin). It allows installing and executing artifacts from repositories and it doesn't require a project.

It's very similar to package managers like yum, apt or gem:

`mvn installation:install -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId`

This will create a shortcut to your class available on the path.

Comment: That looks pretty nice. We actually ended up writing our own little utility outside of mvn to do something very similar. The mvn command takes so long to run even if the plugin isn't doing any work that we abandoned it all together and just wrote some bash scripts to do the downloads and setup the classpath. It's not completely general purpose, but it works well for us.

Comment: Well, installations always take time :-) And when the tool is installed, it creates shortcuts and is run on the system outside of Maven.